# how would i get the outputstream from a library

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, 7zip

I'm making a kotlin app for android that uses a 7z library to unzip some files, i got the libary to work but i would like to add functionality for getting the progress of the unzipping, this is already somewhat implemented into the library because with an argument i can make it print the percentage to the terminal, but now i dont know how to get the stdout into a variable for example.
The library i'm using https://github.com/hzy3774/AndroidP7zip/tree/master

```
P7ZipApi.executeCommand("7z x $externalFilesDir/meta.7z -o$externalFilesDir/meta -p$password -bsp2" )
```

I found doccumentation on java proccesses but that only seem to allow commands of sorts, i dont know what other options would be possible.

Comment: That doesn't look like a library implementation of 7zip instead it simply executes 7z as command-line program. That would mean for a programs info you would need to parse the output stream of the 7z program. BTW I remember that 7zip had some serious security issues last year (not sure if the command-line version was also affected), but that library wasn't updated for at least three years, so be careful. I wouldn't recommend to use it.

Comment: @Robert is there a way i could execute it as a command line program in a proccess inside kotlin then? cause that would let me setup a BufferedReader, on the safety side this app will only unzip my own files so there isnt any risk for security.